# Generate number of mat-cards depending on te user

Tags: javascript, angular

I got simple mat-cards where I got Drag and drop:

```
<div id="pagewrapper">
  <section class="todos-section-wrapper">

    <mat-card class="card">
      <mat-card-header class="card-header">
        <mat-card-title class="card-title">Team</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content class="card-content">

        <div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="todos" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[completedList, roomOneList]"
          class="list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <div class="todo-item" *ngFor="let todo of todos" cdkDrag>{{todo}}</div>
        </div>

      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="card">
      <mat-card-header class="card-header">
        <mat-card-title class="card-title">Room 1</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content class="card-content">

        <div cdkDropList #completedList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="completed"
          [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList, roomOneList]" class="list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <div class="todo-item" *ngFor="let roomTwo of completed" cdkDrag>{{roomTwo}}</div>
        </div>

      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="card">
      <mat-card-header class="card-header">
        <mat-card-title class="card-title">Room 2</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content class="card-content">

        <div cdkDropList #roomOneList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="roomOne"
          [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[completedList, todoList]"
          class="list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <div class="todo-item" *ngFor="let roomOne of roomOne" cdkDrag>{{roomOne}}</div>
        </div>

      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>


  </section>
</div>
```

and there is my app.componen.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  todos: string[] = [
    'Jan Nowak',
    'Jan Kowalski',
    'Monika Nowak',
    'Radek Testowy',
    'Marek Tester',
    'Marian Kowalski'
  ];

  completed: string[] = [
    'Marek Pospieszalski'
  ];

  roomOne: string[] = [
    'Mariusz Kowalski'
  ];


  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {

    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {

      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );

    } else {

      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );

    }

    console.log('todos: '+this.todos);
    console.log('completed: '+this.completed);
    console.log('roomOne: ' + this.roomOne);
    
  }
  
 
}
```

Actually I got 2 mat-card: Room 1 and Room 2
My goal is to achive that I got simple user inputer where I can ask how many rooms you want, then user type for example 4 rooms and he got 4 **mat-cards**
Then he can put people in the rooms.

How Can I dynamically generate mat-cards?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *ngFor to render n cards dynamically.
Have a look that this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iqvkks?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts